# Active Directory/Exchange list users and mobile numbers

Tags: active-directory, exchange, powershell

How can I use Active Directory Powershell or Exchange Management Shell to list all users and they're mobile numbers?

Comment: You should always post the research you have performed as well as code examples of what your trying.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have the Active Directory PowerShell module from RSAT installed, you can use [`Get-ADUser` cmdlet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617241.aspx) to retrieve all users and the value of their [`mobile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms677119(v=vs.85).aspx) attribute, like this:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties mobile
```

Get-ADUser retrieves a number of attributes by default, if you don't need those, use `Select-Object` to pick out the ones you need:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties mobile | Select-Object Name,Mobile
```

Comment: Thanks but I also get a lot of unwanted fields using that. I just want 2 columns, `Name | Mobile` and the users and mobiles listed underneath (similar output to EMS).

Comment: Use `Select-Object` (updated answer)